# Windows 10 Mobile update expiry also July 29th?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, nokia-lumia-535

For PCs, there is a 1 year free update to Windows 10 ending on July 29th 2016. After that date, you have to pay.

Is this applicable also for Windows 10 Mobile? What is the end date for the free update?

(I want to buy a Lumia 535 that does not come with Windows 10 Mobile.)

Comment: i dont think so! imagine once if the mobile os is paid, where would ms be in market share!

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to buy that Lumia 535, there is **no end date** to the free upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile.

[image]

Unfortunately I do not have a source to back this up, mostly because Microsoft has never, not once, so much as hinted at charging money for the upgrade. Just like they never charged money for the upgrade to, say, WP 7.5 or 8.1. And just like no other mobile OS vendor (at least in recent history) has charged money for an OS upgrade. When you think about it, that in itself is all the guarantee you need that the Windows 10 Mobile upgrade will remain free of charge - were Microsoft to make it a paid upgrade, they would completely alienate pretty much all of their remaining users and cause massive uproar.

The only way the upgrade can end up costing you money is if you have to download it over a mobile data connection (but it'd have to be another device's hotspot, because downloading W10M requires a WiFi connection).

Comment: In fact I'm sure they said the upgrade for phones will be free "forever" when they first showcased it on Joe's 1520 (Jan. 20...15 ? If my memories are correct)

Yet since almost no one talks about that, I can't back it up either. But I don't see why they would ask you to pay for a mobile update

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows 10 free upgrade offer will be continued for mobile phone as they use assistive technologies. See [this blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.com/on-the-issues/2016/02/18/making-microsoft-products-accessible-path-forward/#sm.0001s5f8rx18iuekiyguxnjfqf04i) from MS and [this post](http://mspoweruser.com/windows-10-will-continue-free-upgrade-windows-788-1-users-use-assistive-technologies/) in MS PowerUser.